# Large Scale SQL Query over 100 Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml, database

I have recently been asked to produce a simple module for the marketing module of a website, I have been asked to produce a very specific set of results with the raw data accessible via a MySQL database. Now at first I thought was very straight forward however when confronted with the tables I realized I needed to change my approach.

The problem facing me as such, the data I need is a log of the users action while navigating very specific parts of the site. Every action of the user is logged from logging in to logging out, the number of people who visit the site on a daily basis only allow this system to run for about 2days before the data is archived into another table, in total we have 100 tables plus the live, giving me roughly 202 days of data to work with at any one time.

So here is my question.

With the size amount of data that these tables store and the sheer number of archives tables which may or may not be limited to 100, and the client wants ALL the numbers displayed to the screen based on the actions of a specific page how would you recommend going about this?

Querying directly with SQL may or may not be possible based on the database setup so I have considered a few options from XML to serializing the data into a file structure using a chron based on page and data, but ultimately I'm not 100% which route I should take, so I thought to ask, does anyone have any better idea's? and if so please share.

Thanks in advance to anyone and everyone who replies.

Comment: Just A question but, did you know this before you bid on the project?

Comment: Why archive into hundreds of new tables? I can understand why moving old data into a new table might help, but why not move all old data into the *same* archival table? It's not like it's being hit with any queries.

Comment: I think you'd better set up your own, personal, <strike>Jesus</strike> database (preferably on dedicated machine), set the daily job to flush the data from live table to that database (possible denormalizing the data you need before transmitting it), and than just run any query you want on that separate database. That's called OLAP, if I'm not mistaking :)

Comment: Never used a join on that many tables (most I think I have done is 44 tables), but I would expect it to work fairly well, even if very ugly to read. But probably require a dynamically built query unioning the required rows from each table. Depending on the number of users / areas of the site / anything else used to limit the data being viewed it might be easier to run a nightly cron job to aggregate the figures for past days and then just merge in the details for the current day at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to query this data directly.  You want to create intermediate tables that have the information that you need now, and then some.

The exact format depends on the nature of the questions.  For instance, it might be appropriate to have one record for each "session", with columns describing what happens in the session.  Or, if you are only interested in customers, you might make a customer signature, with a bunch of values.

One of the challenges is that the data goes over boundaries between dates.  So, you will have open "logins" in one table versus another.  How much of a problem this poses once again depends on how the data will be used.  However, you should think about strategies for ealing with it.

If you have lots of users with lots of steps on a web site, going against all the data directly would be, shall I say, fun.  Well, if you take a long vacation while the system processes the data, then it might actually be fun.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are getting into the area where you need to get into data warehousing if you want to query your own data.  This means you would like want to perform ETL jobs on your data to get it into a a database schema (star schema, snowflake schema, etc.) which is more conducive for reporting queries.

Personally, I would consider the approach of leveraging some other system like Google Analytics and start logging custom data into it.  That way Google maintains the infrastructure and you get all the report data you want.  You can use Google Analytics to create conversion funnels and most anything you need, however be warned that you must put a good amount of time into actually configuring you code to send custom events, tags, etc. to the Google system.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the concepts of caching. With that you might not need to fetch the data every time from the table.

Comment: Cache 202 days of data? I wonder, how many memory you'll need.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the data is cached... You still need to get it once, somehow. If that's a 100 table query then the problem remains, except you've just used all the OPs RAM.